# Text Field hiding while enabling keypad in blackberry10 cascades qml

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am having a TextField in qml layout, while enabling the keyboard the first TextField is showing and below all the TextField is hiding. How do I solve this issue? [image: text field hiding]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution

`ScrollView {
            scrollViewProperties {
                scrollMode: ScrollMode.Vertical
            }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Add all your views inside a ScrollView. You'll then be able to scroll up to the unreachables items.

Comment: i have added scroll view to the main container any other solutions

Comment: What do you sayexactly ? You already had a scrollView and the problem before asking, or you have just added the scrollview and you still have the problem, or you have added the scrollview and it resolves the problem but you want another solution?